# File duplicate search on save

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm using a C# ASP.NET application i have folder name xyz and in this folder some file are stored like jpg, doc etc with their specific name.

But when i add a file which already exists in this folder, but was saved under different name.

I want to ask how it is possible to find such file that have different name but actually is the same?

Comment: Please give a more meaningful title to your question.

Comment: Please format your question properly, it is difficult to comprehend your problem..!

Comment: Specify the criteria(s) by which files are equal. Size, creation date, what else?

Comment: Are you asking how to find identical files that have different names?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very difficult to understand, but I *think* you're asking how to identify duplicate files:  different files that have the same contents.

One way to do that is to hash the contents of each file (using a hash function such as SHA-1) and store the results in a `Dictionary`, using the hash as the key, and a `List` of filenames as the value.  If two (or more) files have the same contents, they'll have the same hash value, so they'll all be filed under the same key in the dictionary.  After you've hashed all the files and put the results into the dictionary, you can go through its values and check whether any of the lists contain more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

```
void SaveFile(string fileName)
{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/xyz");
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    // comparison algorithm based on size and creation date
    bool exists = (from fi in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
                   where fi.Size == fileInfo.Size &&
                         fi.CreationTimeUtc == fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc
                   select fi).Any();

    // comparison algorithm based on hash
    string fileHash = ComputeHash(fileInfo.FullPath);   
    bool exists = (from fi in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
                   where String.Equals(
                       ComputeHash(fi.FullPath),
                       fileHash,
                       StringComparison.Ordinal)
                   select fi).Any();                       
}
```

A sample how to get the md5 hash of a file, [see more](http://www.google.com/search?q=c#%20md5%20of%20file%20site%3astackoverflow.com).

```
string ComputeHash(string fileName)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        bytes = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(retVal.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you want to know that 2 files are the same file, even though they have a different filename.

I suppose you can read each file byte by byte and compare:

```
public static bool AreEqual(string f1, string f2)
{
    var fi1 = new FileInfo(f1);
    var fi2 = new FileInfo(f2);

    // first check that they are the same size, obviously a pre-req for them being equal 
    if (f1.Length != f2.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var sr1 = new FileStream(f1, FileMode.Open);
    var sr2 = new FileStream(f2, FileMode.Open);

    for (int i = 0; i < f1.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] left = new byte[1];
        byte[] right = new byte[1];
        sr1.Read(left, i, 1);
        sr2.Read(right, i, 1);
        if (left[0] != right[0])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```